# Getting data from a MySQL database that can be used with include()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, include

I have a field in a MySQL database that contains a varchar. This varchar is intended to be a string that will be used to refer to a file location. For example, `/file.php`.

I've managed to grab this varchar and store it in a `$locationarray` using the code below:

```
$query4 = mysql_query("select filelocation from users where username='$username' limit 1");

while($rowloc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query4))
{
    $locationarray = $rowloc['filelocation'];   

}
```

However, when I use `$locationarray` in conjunction with the `include()` function, nothing is displayed on screen?

Is there a way to get data from a MySQL database that can be used with `include()`?

Comment: where are you doing this `include`?

Comment: btw, why the while loop? are you retrieving just one result or are you overwriting every location on the same var?

Comment: Since the varname includes "array", did you mean to push multiple values on it like `$locationarray[] = $rowloc['filelocation']; `?  Try echoing the variable instead of including it so you can verify it's value. Then compare the path as suggested by @adam

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with your include code, I suspect it's with the contents of filelocation.

`/file.php` is an absolute path, so include will look for `file.php` in the root of your system.

> Files are included based on the file
> path given or, if none is given, the
> include_path specified. If the file
> isn't found in the include_path,
> include() will finally check in the
> calling script's own directory and the
> current working directory before
> failing. The include() construct will
> emit a warning if it cannot find a
> file; this is different behavior from
> require(), which will emit a fatal
> error.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Check your error log - if the file isn't found, the log will tell you exactly where `include` is looking.